# Send commands from sh file and stay logged in over ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I want to send a few commands (functions) that are inside a simple .sh file AND stay logged in when ssh-ing to a remote computer.

I've tried many ways, but none have worked so far.
Here's just one:

```
msh(){
    SERVER=$1
    LOCAL=10.20.1.1
    SSHF=`cat /tmp/sshf.sh`
    ssh $SERVER -R 47471:$LOCAL:22 "$SSHF; bash --login"
}
```

I've also tried copying over the file with pipes and streams and whatnot, none have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reserve a terminal at `$SERVER`, you do this with the `-t` switch. If I change your function to:

```
msh(){
    SERVER=$1
    LOCAL=10.20.1.1
    SSHF=`cat /tmp/sshf.sh`
    ssh -t $SERVER -R 47471:$LOCAL:22 "$SSHF; bash --login"
}
```

It seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First copy the file over with `scp` like this `scp /tmp/sshf.sh $SERVER:~`

This will place your script `sshf.sh` in your home directory on `$SERVER` then you can `ssh` into the machine and run it `ssh $SERVER cat ~/sshf.sh`

As a script called `copy_run_stay.sh` with `sshf.sh` containing `echo hello` would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# get server name as argument to script
SERVER=$1
script='sshf.sh' 
# copy script to server
scp $script $SERVER:~
# run script on server
ssh $SERVER cat ~/sshf.sh
# stay on server
ssh $SERVER
```

And would produce:

```
# run the script on laptop
laptop $ ./copy_run_stay.sh
# sshf.sh gets copied to server and ran
server $ hello 
# we are still on the server
server $
```